# Where is mysql.sock?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to configure "Bacula" on my Ubuntu server which was programed with a PostgreSQL preference.

They allow a socket to be used for MySQL but it is missing from my install.  I have tried a few things suggested online but most posts are 3 years old or more.  It is just plain not there.  Where can I get the `mysql.sock` file?

Latest MySQL
Ubuntu Server 18.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be located under `/var/run`, check `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

Comment: AH yes thank you!  No wonder my search found nothing.  It's `mysqld`

Comment: Also if you come here looking for MySQL connection to Bacula, you need to run `apt-get install bacula-director-mysql`